# Trying to use cec-compliance fails with open on /dev/cec0

Tags: v4l2

I'm trying to use the hdmi cec tools that come with the latest Raspian. When I try and run `cec-ctl` or `cec-compliance` I get a fail to open `/dev/cec0`. The kernel modules I have from `lsmod` (partial):

```
videobuf2_dma_contig    20480  1 bcm2835_codec
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_memops       16384  2 videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  3 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
snd_pcm               102400  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
videobuf2_common       45056  4 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
snd                    73728  5 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
videodev              200704  6 bcm2835_codec,v4l2_common,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  36864  2 videodev,v4l2_mem2mem
```

What module/driver do I need for the v4l utils?

Comment: What does `cec-client -m` do?  I'm working on the same problem on my Pi, but that command is able to autodetect and do some things.  Once it's running, send the pi CEC commands and it will print it on the screen